# python regex trying to match the second occurrence of a set of words in a string

Tags: python, regex

i have the following string

```
test 123 Copy complete, now saving to disk (please wait)... Copy complete.test 456 Copy complete, now saving to disk (please wait)... Copy complete. test789
```

I am trying to match the last/2nd occurrence of "now saving to disk"

```
r'^.*now saving to disk.*(?=now saving to disk).*$'
```

I thought i could use ?= look ahead to have it look ahead to the 2nd occurrence, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to skip the first occurrence of your text and match the second/last occurrence,

```
^.*(now saving to disk).*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AnnKJu/1)**

As I have used `.*` which captures any text in a greedy way, hence it only stops at the last occurrence and matches the last occurrence of your text and matches that.

Also, your regex `^.*now saving to disk.*(?=now saving to disk).*$` is almost correct, except that you shouldn't have used `?=` in your group, which actually made it a look ahead expression instead of just capturing it in your intended first group. So if you just remove `?=` from your regex, even your regex works perfectly fine and is also best performance wise.

**[Demo for your regex after removing `?=`](https://regex101.com/r/AnnKJu/2)**

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

To get the last occurrence, just use:

```
^.*(now saving to disk)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRj9GC/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline, as many as possible. This will take you to the end of the string
- `(now saving to disk)` - matches `now saving to disk` after backtracking to the last occurrence of the phrase and captures it in Group 1

**Solution 2:**

To get the 2nd occurrence, just grab whatver is in group 1:

```
^(?:.*?(now saving to disk)){2}
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRj9GC/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?:.*?(now saving to disk)){2}` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except new line, as few as possible, followed by the phrase `now saving to disk`. This is repeated twice to get you the required phrase.

**Solution 3:**

Here's is another Regex that makes use of negative lookahead to make sure that the phrase is not repeated anymore before the end of the string. This will again fetch you the last occurrence of `now saving to disk`

```
(now saving to disk)(?!.*\1.*$)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRj9GC/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `(now saving to disk)` - matches and captures `now saving to disk` in group 1
- `(?!.*\1.*$)` - negative lookahead to make sure whatever is present in Group 1 does not come later in the string before the end of the String